# Instanciar elemento de un XML en Android

Tags: android, xml

Tengo un método donde estoy tratando de instanciar un TextView para obtener su cadena de string y poder realizar una actualización y mostrarla en pantalla. Mi problema es que no puedo referenciarla, tengo el código así.

```
private void actualizarInfoSaldo() {
    Saldo saldo;
    TextView textoSaldo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saldoTextView); //FALLA !!!!

    OperacionesBaseDatos bdOperaciones= new OperacionesBaseDatos();
    saldo = bdOperaciones.leerSaldo();

    String saldoStr = "Saldo actual: " + String.valueOf(saldo.getSaldo()) + " $";

    CharSequence charSqc;
    charSqc = saldoStr;
    textoSaldo.setText(charSqc);
}
```

ERROR:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.iberd.actionvalue, PID: 12210
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.iberd.actionvalue.ScreenSlidePageFragment.actualizarInfoSaldo(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:240)
                                                   at com.example.iberd.actionvalue.ScreenSlidePageFragment.cambioSaldo(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:218)
                                                   at com.example.iberd.actionvalue.ScreenSlidePageFragment$1.onClick(ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:132)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/saldo"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/letra"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

El tema es que tengo varios xml que se referencia desde varias activitys, pero en todos los casos el id del textView es saldoTextView

Comment: Qué falla ? qué error muestra ?

Comment: Donde está ese método? En el MainActivity o en otra clase?

Comment: Si estas llamandolo dentro de un fragent, necesitas usar la `View`, en onCreate asigna el TextView de esta manera: `textoSaldo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saldoTextView);`
En `rootView` coloca la `View` que estes usando

Comment: @Israel ahora si referencio bien el TextView y mediante **System.out.println(textoSaldo.getText());** saco el contenido del TextView en la terminal. El problema es que a la hora de setear textoSaldo por algo que yo establezco me da un fallo acerca de un nulo, lo adjunto a la pregunta del post. La falla ocurre aquí : **textoSaldo.setText(charSqc);**. A que puede deberse? saludos.

Comment: por cierto adjunta tu respuesta a respuestas para así poder darte tu voto positivo. Ya que el error que tengo ahora ya no es el que tenia en un principio.

Comment: Deberías añadir también tu xml para poder comprobar cual es el error.

Comment: Hola @EduardoMéndez antes de actualizar mi respuesta con nuevo error que tienes, podrías probar a eliminar la linea `textoSaldo.setText(charSqc);`y ver si el error continúa ? En el log aparece `TextView.getText()`pero donde indicas que da el error es en `setText()` Por si acaso revisa si estas llamando getText() en algun sitio, ya que no veo error en el código. A excepción de que estés extendiendo la clase de Fragment y aun falte añadir la View al iniciar el TextView (ejemplo en mi respuesta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas llamandolo dentro de un `fragent`, necesitas usar la `View`, en `onCreateView` asigna el `TextView` de esta manera:

```
TextView textoSaldo;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tu_fragment, container, false);
   textoSaldo = rootView.findViewById(R.id.saldoTextView);

}
```

Comment: He sustituido el ViewGroup que tenia por el un View normal para poder llevar a cabo tu recomendacion. Encuanto al getText fue una prueba que hice para ver si me recogia el valor y si me lo recoje en cambio cuando trato de introducir  el setText falla. Es un error bastante raro. Que pueda hacer un getText de un objeto y no pueda hacer un setText

Comment: el log de error estaba mal, acabo de actualizarlo en el post

Comment: debajo de este mismo código de ejemplo, coloca `textoSaldo.setText("prueba");` Así se podrá ver si esta el objeto instanciado correctamente, o el error viene de otro lado.

Comment: falla tambien realizando un seteo desde el onCreate. Me da el mismo fallo lo unico que esta vez el error se propaga en la linea que acabamos de añadir